# Best way to push alert to webpage through php/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Just looking for some guru advice/tips as am building a home automation website for our new house.  Will have a php website that each PC (about 10-15) throughout the house will be able to access to perform tasks (eg play movies, music, control lights etc).

On this site, I'd also like to be able to ping a message to all PCs as a handy copy/paste tool (always needing to send links between pcs to view in different room).

What's the best way to go about this? Should I have a jQuery script that's making ajax requests every x secs? Should my php script do this? Would like to make it as efficient as possible, so any clever suggestions or wise words would be most appreciated!

Comment: So you have a specifc problem. You don't know what to do. How can we say what's useful in your case? It would be helpful to know what you've tried so far and into which concrete problem you did run with your code. As long as you even haven't started, well who can say what works for you if not yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You really can't push to each PC so that leaves you with requesting every x seconds (would not recommend anything under 60 seconds). Your going to need a couple of pieces here.

- The most efficient way would be to create a Web Service tied into a database to store "messaging".
- A ajax script to call the web service and check for messages, then display them to screen (by whatever means you prefer).

Good Luck.

Comment: Given the limited number of possible clients, more than once a minute isn't crazy (though I also don't see why it would be needed) unless the web server is on an old machine.

Comment: @Tom I agree with you. For this purpose there is no point in loading down the web service server with low priority tasks (such as this) in favor of higher priority tasks such as doing what it was purposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would just poll a PHP url that returns JSON for messages. Ask the script for messages since the last time you checked in (so the JavaScript on the page would maintain a global variable of the last check-in). The one thing would be when you load/ reload the page in the browser, as you don't want to get all the messages ever, so have the PHP side only return messages in the last 5 minutes or some sensible duration.

Comment: Why not give each message a ID. After you've recieved a message you can ask for any new message since then. This would ensure that you don't transmit any duplicate messages.

Comment: Yeah, that's nicer. So the initial call would not pass an id and the script returns all messages in the last x minutes.

Comment: For example, or the last 10 messages or so. If there are 10 PCs, maybe the last 20 messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the pusher api. http://pusher.com/docs Instead of the clients querying your server every x seconds, your server will push data to the clients in real-time.